# Can brahmins of different regions such as AP/KA or north India wear PurvaShikha or is it only for brahmins of Kerala and Tamil Nadu?

Tags: vedas, dharma-shastras, brahmins, varna

I have a friend who is from Karnataka but was wearing a purvashikha... is it permitted??

Comment: it depends on the family tradition